# Drools with last version of Oracle JDK

Tags: drools, drools-kie-server, kie-server

Would it be possible to use the latest version of Drools 7.63.0.Final with the latest version of Tomcat 10.0.14 and Java Oracle JDK 17 LTS ?

I notice that the latest version of Drools7.63.0.Final can only work/is supproted with Wildfly 23 which only supports JDK 11 (not the last one, which is not recommended) !!!

What if we have to use the latest versions of Drools with Wildfly 26/tomcat 10 and java 17 ?

Comment: Are you using Drools _library_ or something else? Kie server, perhaps? Drools library itself runs perfectly fine on JDK 17 (though I use the OpenJDK not anything from Oracle) with Tomcat in a Spring boot application. But since you mention wildfly compatibility I'm thinking you're possibly talking about something else, like Kie server or JBPM or something.

Comment: yes, I am using the Drools Workbench and the Drools Kieserver on wildfly server. 
Their last version are compatible with the Tomcat and JDK last versions ? From what I have seen, I thought they are only compatible with wildfly 23 :/

Comment: Like I said, i use the _library_, not these other applications. The _library_ can be used with the latest JDK and Tomcat; I can't speak to the workbench and kie server.